# C# Date format-What format of date is this

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working on a rest service in C# and receiving a string parameter which looks like this:

```
2018-08-01T00:00:00+10000
```

First of all, I am not sure what format of date is this, I have been told its probably ISO 8601 but when I try to convert it into string to eventually convert it into Datetime object, I get:

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: Please post the code you are using to get that error

Comment: Have you first search on SO? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25711907/2777098 may be what you are looking for

Comment: it's not the code it's the data. (probably since she didn't post her code)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the answer below helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# know how to parse ISO 8601, and the code is easy:

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2018-08-01T00:00:00+1000");
```

in your question you added another 0 at the end (+10000 instead of +1000) which is not allowed by the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thank you sooo very much, that helped. Now does that convert it into UTC time or Local time?  date will be local??

Comment: @Sarah Your question was answered. Please accept the answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. The second question can be posted as a new question.